# I was trying to create a character counter, but I ended up with this

Tags: batch-file

I'm new to batch and I tried creating a character counter for fun, but I ended up with a seemingly random number generator that eventually displays an error code saying "Invalid number. Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision."

```
@echo off
Title Character Counter
set /a count=0
set /a new=0
:next
cls 
echo %new%
echo %count%
set /a new=%new%%new2%
set /p new2=
set /a count=%count%+1
goto next
```

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do.  I am not understanding what you mean to accomplish with "a character counter".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to count the characters in a string?
*(the code that you displayed is a bit of an endless loop!)*

Here is a quick and dirty function that will count the characters in a string (there are other ways of doing it):

```
:charStringLength
@echo off
set /a _strlength=0
:: _strlength is is your counter

echo %* > _tempfile.txt
:: store the string in a temporary file
:: the asterisk is a wild card to collect all parameters,
:: takes care of spaces in the string

FOR %%? IN (_tempfile.txt) DO ( SET /A _strlength=%%~z? - 3 )
:: count the characters in the file
:: less a carriage return that echo pops in when creating the file, and
:: less the standard 2 eof characters

del _tempfile.txt & rem zap temp file
echo: [%*] is %_strlength% characters long

:: /charStringLength
```

some test results:

```
>charStringLength abcde 12345
 [abcde 12345] is 11 characters long
>
>charStringLength abcde12345
 [abcde12345] is 10 characters long
>
```